# instantiate class in python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a Node object inside a script and use it an in instance variable. In the code shown below, the line `root = Node('')` gives me an error saying undefined variable Node.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #url = ''
    #processWords(url)
    currentWord = []
    root = Node('')
    curr = root
    words = ['adelaide', 'ahmedabad', 'calcutta', 'california', 'chicago', 'chennai', 'delhi', 'dubai', 'melbourne', 'mumbai']
    process(words)
    play()

class Node:
    def __init__(self, char):
        self.char = char
        self.children = set()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `Node` *before* you try to use it.

Comment: thanks! I have to wait 10 minutes before I can accept your answer. Also, how/where do I declare variables that I want to be accessible by any method (like an instance variable)?

Comment: You've done that already with `self.char` and `self.children`.

Comment: I meant in the script. For example, the variable curr is set in the main function. But when I use it in a method, I get an error saying: local variable 'curr' referenced before assignment. It thinks curr is a local variable, when I want it to be an 'instance' variabel

Comment: You're mixing up terms. Instance variables belong to instances of classes, like you `children` belongs to an instance of `Node`. You should post a separate question if you're still having trouble.

Comment: That's why I put instance in quotes! I want curr to be accessible by all methods of my script. I'm not sure if global variable is the right term...